# setLocation without refreshing webpage

Tags: javascript, html

is it possible to change the location url without the browser refreshing the page ?

imagine I want the user to change some values on some fields and as a consequence of this 
to update is url (following the question mark)

so www.mysite.com/mypage?level=1&fav_fruit=apple&fav_food=pasta&...

the idea is that if it changes the 'favourite food' i might change the url only

www.mysite.com/mypage?level=1&fav_fruit=apple&fav_food=rice&...

but I don't want to refresh the page.

why ? so he/she can continue to use the page and when he/she is tired he can bookmark it the way it left it (given a good name to it)

any idea ?

I will do this with javascript.

Comment: Why not just have a save button which creates the bookmark for them instead of making them do it their self.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to update the part after the question mark without refreshing the page, but you can update the URL hash (so it looks like http://domain.com/file.php#fav_fruit=apple). I don't know how to do it in plain old JavaScript but I have done this using [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) and the [jQuery.address plugin](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/).

You can then set the textbox to update the URL every time the value is changed by doing something like the following:

```
$("#mytextbox").change(function(){
  $.address.parameter("fav_fruit", $(this).value());
});
```

The good thing with this plugin is that you can attach a function so that you can detect when the URL is changed (i.e. when the bookmark is reloaded):

```
$.address.externalChange(function(){
   var favFruit = $.address.parameter("fav_fruit");
   // Set any textboxes, values, etc
});
```

By default, the plugin will create a history action everytime a value is update (so you can press back/forward). You wouldn't want this so you'd have to have this before you set any values:

```
$.address.history(false);
```

---

**Update**: Here's what it looks like in plain old JavaScript:

```
// Stores name/value pairs that have changed
var updatedValues = [];

// Updates or adds an element to 'updatedValues'
function change(obj) {
    updatedValues[obj.name] = obj.value;
    setHash();
}

// Gets all the changes variables/values and sets the hash
function setHash() {
    var arr = [];
    for (x in updatedValues) {
        arr.push(x + '=' + escape(updatedValues[x]));
    }
    location.hash = arr.join('&');
}

// Returns an object to return the values from the hash string
function readHash() {
    var locationHashParts = location.hash.substr(1).split('&');
    var params = {};

    for (paramName in locationHashParts) {
        var keypair = locationHashParts[paramName].split('=');
        params[keypair[0]] = unescape(keypair[1]);
    }

    return params;
}
```

It's not pretty, but it works. `change` is what you set your form elements to call and it will set the URL hash with the required bits. When you want to set the values in the form fields (for example, when you load the page), you call the `readHash` to get an object with all the parameters/values in the `location.hash` field.

Example of it working at http://jsfiddle.net/ENHFN/ (although you can't see the location hash change, it uses the variable). I kept getting errors when I tried to separate it out.

Comment: Plain old javascript? location.hash

Comment: True - that could be set like that but then you have to do the serialising/de-serialising yourself. Although I think I'm just applying too much of how I used it myself.

Answer (score 2):

For practical cross-browser purposes, Jonathons answer is correct, but **using HTML5 it is actually possible to change the URL without refreshing the page!**

It is only supported by FireFox and Chrome so far, but as usual the others will adopt it sooner or later (read: later). Anyway, you do it like this:

```
window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", "new-url");
```

The third parameters is the URL that you want to set. The other two are for doing more advanced things, and you don't have to care about those if all you want to do is change the URL. If you want to know the whole story, read [this](http://www.spoiledmilk.dk/blog/?p=1922).

Comment: +1 Looking forward to being able to use this properly (and replaceState, etc). Unfortunately the projects I've used this technique for have all been 'lowest common denominator' ones.